# Mimicing classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I am attempting to make my life in Javascript a little bit easier (At least for my work environment). I am attempting to move all my Javascript object creation methods into a "class". I have the following code (To create a hyperlink):

```
function QuickDOM()
{
   this.createElement = function(tag)
   {
       var element;
       if (tag === undefined || typeof tag != 'string')
       {
           element = document.createElement("div");
       }
       else
       {
           element = document.createElement(tag);
       }
       return element;
    };

    this.A = function(hyperlink, content)
    {
       var element = QuickDOM.createElement("a");
       element.setAttribute("href", hyperlink);
       element.innerHTML = content;
       return element;
    };
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about mimicing a "class" in Javascript? I currently get the following error in Chrome whilst executing `new QuickDOM().A("www.google.com", "Google");`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function QuickDOM()
```

Can anyone offer me any suggestions as to why this is not working.

NOTE: I was using [this](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js) as a guide.

Comment: In `tag === undefined || typeof tag != 'string'` the first test is redundant. `typeof tag != 'string'` covers it.

Comment: You should study the DOM API and its hierarchy (Node -> HTMLElement -> typeOfElement, etc.) because you'll likely be replicating it. Oh, and not all A elements are links, some are anchors and don't have an HREF but do have a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `createElement` or `A` you have to create an instance of `QuickDOM`:

```
var quickDOM = new QuickDOM();
var element = quickDOM.createElement("a");
```

In your `A` method you should use `this` instead of `QuickDOM`:

```
var element = this.createElement("a");
```

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you - it was one of those mind-blanking problems :D

Answer (score 1):

You're adding instance methods and then attempting to access them statically within your code.

Try replacing `QuickDOM.createElement("a")` with `this.createElement("a")`.

Also, the way you're assigning instance methods is generally considered bad practice. I could see some merit if you were doing it that way to have *private* variables, but seeing as you're not, you may want to make those methods exist on the prototype instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your `A` method you are using the function instead of an instance of the object. This code:

```
var element = QuickDOM.createElement("a");
```

would be using the instance that you are in:

```
var element = this.createElement("a");
```

However, as you don't have any use for more than one instance of that object, you should just create an object instead of having a constructor function:

```
var QuickDOM = {
   createElement: function(tag)
   {
       var element;
       if (tag === undefined || typeof tag != 'string')
       {
           element = document.createElement("div");
       }
       else
       {
           element = document.createElement(tag);
       }
       return element;
    },

    A: function(hyperlink, content)
    {
       var element = this.createElement("a");
       element.setAttribute("href", hyperlink);
       element.innerHTML = content;
       return element;
    }
}
```

Now you would just use the object to call the methods:

```
var link = QuickDOM.A("www.google.com", "Google");
```